# Razor Pages Partial Views with routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'd like to have Razor Pages as partial views but also being able to get them separately as HTML fragments so I can update them with AJAX.

If I put a `@page` at the top of my partial view, it gets routed but its model object will be `null`. If I remove `@page`, the model will be valid however I can no longer GET the partial view separately.

How can I have the cshtml be routed **and** have a valid model at the same time? I'm on ASP.NET Core 2.1 and upgrading is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. Just create a partial view with the HTML you're wanting to share, and then call that partial view in your Razor Page. Then, you can use the partial view directly when you need that.

**_MyPartialView.cshtml**

```
@model MyPartialViewModel

<div>Here's my HTML</div>
```

**MyPage.cshtml**

```
@page MyPageModel

<partial name="_MyPartialView" model="Model.MyPartialViewModelInstance" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I put a @page at the top of my partial view, it gets routed but its model object will be null. If I remove @page, the model will be valid however I can no longer GET the partial view separately.

Partial Pages or Views are Razor files containing snippets of HTML and server-side code to be included in any number of pages or layouts. Partial pages can be used to break up complex pages into smaller units, thereby reducing the complexity and allowing teams to work on different units concurrently.

Just like standard Razor pages, partial pages support the `@model` directive specifying the type for the partial's data model. All of the rendering methods have overloaded versions that take a model to be consumed in the partial.

Note that the partial page does not feature an`@page` directive. That would make the file a full Razor Page and will lead to a `NullReferenceException`related to the model not being declared when the framework attempts to invoke it - because there is no associated PageModel file. You could refer to [Partial Pages in a Razor Pages application](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages).